# Прошу помочь с html input:number

Tags: javascript, html

Есть в страничке `<input type="number" name="number">`
У меня не получается сделать так, чтобы инпут не принимал символ минус.
Я понимаю, что нужно добавить атрибут `onchange=""`, но что прописать?

Прошу помощи в написании кода.

Comment: А просто сделать `min="0"` не вариант?

Comment: @andreymal  :)))) да min='0' решил все, спасибо

Comment: @django_starter: Сомневаюсь, что только в атрибуте дело ;-) Будьте добры, прочитайте мой ответ.

Comment: @UModeL да ваш код, уже на проф уровне! спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, протестировав и подытожив предыдущие ответы, сделал вывод, что ни один из вариантов не решает задачу полностью. В разных вариантах - разные недочёты:

- При вводе некорректного символа, затирается уже существующее значение;
- Если вернуть каретку (текстовый курсор) в начало, с помощью стрелок или мыши, то можно ввести символы `-`, `+`, `.`, `,` и продолжить ввод числа;
- Уменьшая число нативной кнопкой, при переходе через ноль, попеременно меняется значение с *0* на *1*;
- Возможность вставить ранее перечисленные символы через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>;
- Избыточность кода.

---

Пробуем избавиться от недостатков обозначенных выше:

```css
input:valid { background: #dfd; } input:invalid { background: #fdd; }
```

```html
<input type="number" 
  
  min="0" 
  onkeypress="return (event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58);" 
  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');" 
  onpaste="return /^[0-9]+$/g.test((event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text'));"
  
  pattern="^[0-9]+$" 
  required
/>
```

> *В данном примере, два последних атрибута (*`pattern` *и* `required`*), а
>   также CSS, нужны только для наглядности. Но, возможно, они Вам
>   пригодятся в дальнейшем.*

---

Минусы тоже присутствуют:

- Можно вводить только целые числа (*об этом ничего не упомянуто в вопросе*);
- Давно обещают прекращение поддержки `event.keyCode` (*возможно, код придётся подправить*).

Comment: Ограничивать ввод скриптами нет смысла. Если введён минус, то `min="0"` просто не позволит отправить форму, а значит городить скрипты нет никакой необходимости и все ответы здесь чепуха :)

Comment: @andreymal: Форма подразумевается, но конкретно её не было во вводной. Потому такое количество вариантов. А "чепуха" может ещё не раз пригодиться кому-нибудь, т.к. применима не только для `input[type=number]`. Создаю контент и не подвешиваю вопросы ответами в комментариях ;-)

Comment: Если инпут не используется в форме, значит он используется в скриптах, а в них достаточно сделать `checkValidity()` так что ответы всё равно чепуха :)

Comment: @andreymal: А почему Вы об этом в комментариях пишете, а не в ответе?

Answer (score 2):

Так в начале символ - (/-/) или любая не цифра (/\D/) не ставится, но если цифры уже присутствуют, то инпут обнуляется

```
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/-/, '')">
```

Или

```
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, '')">
```

---

А так проверяется на меньше 0. И возвращается по модулю, если меньше.

```
<input type="number" oninput="if(this.value < 0) this.value *= -1">
```

---

Можно и так: любое не число будет возвращать прежнее число.

```
<input type="number" data-value="" oninput="if(this.value)this.setAttribute('data-value', this.value); else this.value = this.getAttribute('data-value');">
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью JS

```js
const reg = /[^0-9]/,
  input = document.querySelector('#example');
input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(reg, '');
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="example">
```

Comment: Теперь инпут не принимает символы 0-9

Comment: вроде принимает

Comment: Принимает, верно.

Answer (score 2):

Пример на чистом js:

```js
// Запрет ввода букв в числовом поле
    var count = document.getElementById("count");

    if (!!count) {
        count.onkeypress = function(e) {
            e = e || event;

            if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) return;

            var chr = getChar(e);

            // с null надо осторожно в неравенствах,
            // т.к. например null >= '0' => true
            // на всякий случай лучше вынести проверку chr == null отдельно
            if (chr == null) return;

            if (chr < '0' || chr > '9') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function getChar(event) {
        if (event.which == null) {
            if (event.keyCode < 32) return null;
            return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) // IE
        }

        if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) {
            if (event.which < 32) return null;
            return String.fromCharCode(event.which) // остальные
        }

        return null; // специальная клавиша
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" max="999" min="0" maxlength="10" id="count" required>
```

Пример на jQuery:

```js
$("#input").keypress(function(e) {
  if (
    e.which != 8 &&
    e.which != 0 &&
    e.which != 46 &&
    (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" min="0" />
```